# Progress Marker along Footer of Document

Tags: tikz-pgf, footer

I am interested in putting some progress markers along the footer, like a (short) vertical line (marker) that represents each chapter, and another marker to indicate the current page in the document, where the position is such that `0.0\linewidth` corresponds to the start of the document, and `1.0\linewidth` is the end of the document.

Therefore, the chapter markers should be fixed, ie first chapter marked somewhere to the left, with the final chapter marked somewhere to the right. The page marker should move left-to-right as the document progresses.

Would someone be so kind as to steer me in the right direction, since every page has a footer, and the final chapters are not known until the document is compiled at least once, I am at a loss as to the best way to retain this information so that the markers for each chapter can be rendered on every page.

I don't have any MWE, cause frankly, I am not sure where to start with this one, but I'd really like to include it in my thesis.

Here is a schematic of what I am looking for:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: How do you calculate the progress? Relative number of pages, i.e. current page / total pages?

Comment: Almost `(Current - Start)/(Total - Start)`, and if start = 0, then this reduces to `Current/Total`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xassoccnt` and determine the number of pages beforehand and calculate the relative page number with `\fpeval` from `xfp`

The advantage of `xassoccnt` over `lastpage` is that resetting of page numbers has no effect on the total page number and it provides an expandable page number value, in contrast to `\pageref` (well, this could be circumvented with `\getpagerefnumber` from `refcount` package).

Please note that two runs are necessary to provide the correct information. In the first run, nothing is drawn.

This relative page progress is given as multiplier to `\linewidth` and a Ti*k*Z rectangle is drawn in the page footer.

The procedure would be very similar for chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\NewDocumentCounter{pages}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{pages}
\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}


\newcommand{\pageprogress}{%
  \ifnum\TotalValue{totalpages}>0
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[left color=yellow,right color=red,fill] (0,0) rectangle (\fpeval{\number\value{pages}/\TotalValue{totalpages}}\linewidth,0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\pageprogress}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\blindtext[500]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Storing the chapter start pages and counting their relativ positions according to total page numbers and placing a marker for the local page counter.

**Note: This is not failsafe yet**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[redefinelabel=false]{xassoccnt}

\NewDocumentCounter{chapters,localpages}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalpages}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{chapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{localpages,totalpages}
\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{chapter}{totalchapters}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \l_nicolas_chapter_pages_prop

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn {Nxx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn {Nx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set:Nn {Nx}


\cs_new:Npn \getchapterpage#1{%
  \prop_item:Nn \l_nicolas_chapter_pages_prop {#1start}
}


\cs_new:Npn \storechapterallpages {%
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1} {\TotalValue{totalchapters}}{%
    \prop_put:Nxx \l_nicolas_chapter_pages_prop {##1} {\getpagerefnumber{autochapter::##1}}
  }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{1} {\TotalValue{totalchapters}}{%
   % \int_set:Nx \l_tmpa_int {##1-1}
   % \int_set:Nx \l_tmpb_int {##1+1}
    \prop_put:Nxx \l_nicolas_chapter_pages_prop {##1start} {\fp_eval:n { (\prop_item:Nn \l_nicolas_chapter_pages_prop {##1}-1)/\TotalValue{totalpages}}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\runinloop}[4]{%
  \int_step_function:nnnN {#1} {#2} {#3} #4
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawchapterruleandmarker}[1]{%
  \draw[line width=1pt,blue] (\getchapterpage{#1}\linewidth,-3pt) -- (\getchapterpage{#1}\linewidth,5pt);
  \node[below,inner sep=0pt] (chapter#1) at (\getchapterpage{#1}\linewidth,-5pt) {#1};
  \shade[line width=1pt,red,ball color=red] (\fpeval{\number\value{localpages}/\TotalValue{totalpages}}\linewidth,2pt) circle (0.2);
}


\newcommand{\pageprogress}{%
  \ifnum\TotalValue{totalchapters}>0
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw[line width=1pt,blue] (0,2pt) -- (\linewidth,2pt);%
    \runinloop{1}{1}{\TotalValue{totalchapters}}{%
      \drawchapterruleandmarker%
    }%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\pageprogress}
}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  }{%
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \label{autochapter::\number\value{chapters}}% Provide an automatic label
  }{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}
  \storechapterallpages%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}


\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{First}
\blindtext[20]

\chapter{Second}
\blindtext[40]

\chapter{Third}

\blindtext[100]

\chapter{Fourth}
\blindtext[10]


\chapter{Fifth}
\blindtext[50]


\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Most likely because the first run will have an empty `totalpages` value. It is fixed now

Comment: I will try to provide a version with does not need `fancyhdr`, using tikz overlays later on

Comment: Thanks. But what I really wanted was a line, with a series of vertical markers to indicate the point where each chapter starts. This should be the same on every page, and therefore, every page needs to be aware where every chapter starts relative to the whole document. once that is done, then a floating marker can be positioned along the line to indicate the current page. I can do the latter part based on what you have provided, but it is the first part which is tricky in my opinion...

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: The chapter start page can be obtained by placing a label for each chapter, perhaps automatically and then retrieve the page with `\getpagerefnumber{chapterlabel}` from `refcount` package, that macro is expandable and can be used in calculations

Comment: right, but will this need to be hard-coded for each desired marker? Or will a marker be picked up for each chapter regardless of how many chapters are in the document. Perhaps one could get a list of all labels that matches a regex term, like in pseudo `\foreach \x in {<REGEX MATCH>}{do tikz code}`

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: I'll thinking about it.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: See the update, please

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I had in mind. This solution depends on LaTeX3?

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: Yes, since L3 is easier here. It's possible with usual TeX or LaTeX2e as well

Comment: I am not familiar with the LaTeX2e syntax, will it compile as usual? Using say XeTeX?

Comment: @NicholasHamilton LaTeX2e is what you use in general. LaTeX3 is the more complicated looking stuff. If you have an up to date system, everything will work fine, even with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: what Johannes_B wrote ;-)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant to say "I am not familiar with the LaTeX3 syntax, will it compile as usual? Using say XeTeX?"

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: Should work with `XeLaTeX` out of the box.

Comment: Neither of these worked with LuaTeX 1.07 (TL 2018)

Comment: @Krishna: I never claimed that it would work with LuaLaTeX, especially Lua seems to be broken recently

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  Sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn't say you did. But another member here did: " If you have an up to date system, everything will work fine, even with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX" ..... Okay, my thesis is about to be uploaded in the next day or so to my university's repo after which I cannot change anything. Can you please help me to get this effect with LuaTeX?

Comment: @Krishna: Sorry, my time is limited and I can't help you here. I doubt also that this feature is really a good idea for a thesis